# Автоматическое закрытие браузера после выполнения теста

Tags: python, selenium

Начал изучать тестирование, использую selenium + python для автоматизации, заметил такую проблему, если сам тест описывать в классе, то по завершению теста, браузер автоматически закрывается.

```py
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\****** *****\Desktop\kodtest\python\AutoTesting\chromedriver.exe')
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.get("https://stepik.org/lesson/25969/step/12")
        time.sleep(5)

        textarea = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".textarea")
        textarea.send_keys('get()')
        time.sleep(1)

        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".submit-submission")

        submit_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

Test()
```

Если написать тест без использования классов, тогда все работает как надо, подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Закрытие происходит из-за того, что переменная экземпляра `webdriver.Chrome` становится мусором, после отработки кода. Экземпляр класса `selenium.webdriver.Chrome` содержит экземпляр класса `Service`. У последнего есть метод `__del__` который вызывается, когда экземпляр разрушается во время процесса сбора мусора. Метод, в свою очередь, останавливает службу и заставляет окно браузера `Chrome` закрываться. Из возможных решений: сделать переменную `driver` глобальной либо переписать метод `__del__`

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с подобной проблемой, помогло банально использование Firefox вместо Chrome. Честно говорю, почему конкретно так происходит не знаю. Еще не разбирался но фак на лицо если использовать Firefox ну и соответственно rgeckodriver.exe вместо chromedriver.exe, то браузер не закрываеться после завершения теста.